# How do I convert the first 32 bits of the fractional part of a Float into a Word32?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, sha256, sha

Say I have a Float. I want the first 32 bits of the fractional part of this Float? Specifically, I am looking at getting this part of the sha256 pseudo-code working ([from the wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256_.28a_SHA-2_variant.29_pseudocode))

```
# Note 1: All variables are unsigned 32 bits and wrap modulo 232 when calculating
# Note 2: All constants in this pseudo code are in big endian

# Initialize variables
# (first 32 bits of the fractional parts of the square roots of the first 8 primes 2..19):
h[0..7] := 0x6a09e667, 0xbb67ae85, 0x3c6ef372, 0xa54ff53a, 0x510e527f, 0x9b05688c, 0x1f83d9ab, 0x5be0cd19
```

I naively tried doing floor (((sqrt 2) - 1) * 2^32), and then converting the returned integer to a Word32. This does not at all appear to be the right answer. I figured that by multipling by 2^32 power, I was effectively left shifting it 32 places (after the floor). Obviously, not the case. Anyway, long and the short of it is, how do I generate h[0..7] ?

Comment: Note that there is not 32 bits of precision of anything in a Float.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get h[0..7] is to copy the hex constants from the Wikipedia page. That way you know you will have the correct ones.

But if you really want to compute them:

```
scaledFrac :: Integer -> Integer
scaledFrac x =
    let s = sqrt (fromIntegral x) :: Double
    in  floor ((s - fromInteger (floor s)) * 2^32)

[ printf "%x" (scaledFrac i) | i <- [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19] ]
```

Comment: I think he wants to get the first bits of the representation.

Comment: He wants the bits my code gives him.  I checked with the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: Haha, yes, I can't believe I didn't think of just copying and pasting the constants myself. I guess I now have two ways of generating h[0..7]. Thank you

Comment: I am trying to understand the computation but I can't seem to grasp why the fractional part is multiplied by 2^32. Could you please explain?

Comment: @STT Computing `s - fromInteger (floor s)` gives a number in the interval (0,1(.  To get a 32 bit integer we multiply by 2^32.